# How to decompress and run .app?

Tags: terminal, high-sierra, mojave, zip, compression

I'm trying to execute an AppleScript .app thats compressed.

```
unzip -p file.app.zip | open -
```

or

```
open < $(unzip -p file.app.zip)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: did you try it ? what happens

Comment: It just prints the `open` help options

Comment: Open what ? Where ? unzip will create new folder (with same name as zip folder)

Comment: It's a little shell script I wrote. Admittedly, using a pipe is complicating this. But I'd like to know how to do it. The `-p` option with unzip prints the contents using stdout

Comment: let me give you some points for trying

Comment: There is a reason that apps are distributed on.dmg. You can mount the disk that is compressed an run th app. Other Unix tolls don't treat the app as one thing but a load of separate files and directories

Comment: @Buscar웃, You said, "... unzip will create new folder (with same name as zip folder)", **that is not true with the `-p` _option_** used in the OP, e.g. `unzip -p ...`! From the `unzip` _man page_: "`-p     extract files to pipe (stdout).`"

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the `open` command to open content from `stdin`.  `open` can be made to read from `stdin` but it will open the contents in at text editor--which isn't what you want.

**Try using `osascript` directly:**
If the zipped file is simply AppleScript, then you accomplish this with the following.

```
unzip -p file.zip | osascript -
```

From the `osascript` manpage:

> osascript will look for the script in one of the following three places:
>
> 1. Specified line by line using -e switches on the command line.
> 2. Contained in the file specified by the first filename on the command line.  This file may be plain text or a compiled script.
> 3. Passed in using standard input.  This works only if there are no filename arguments; to pass arguments to a STDIN-read script, you must explicitly specify '-' for the script name.

Comment: Did you actually test to see what you posted works? I'm asking because it errors out in my testing.

Comment: Of course.  The command does assume that the unzipped file is plain text AppleScript commands.

Comment: @user3439894, see my previous comment. This solution works for plain ole AppleScript.  Your answer is more appropriate given an AppleScript application.

Comment: @ephsmith, thank you for the answer, but this also errors for me with: `0:1: syntax error: A unknown token can't go here. (-2740)`. My test .zip contains an AppleScript with the following: `do shell script "touch /Users/$USER/Desktop/test"`

Answer (score 1):

As you are dealing with a zip compressed *application* `.app`, which is an *application bundle* with many files in it, I believe you'll have to extract the app to disk first to open it, because the `open` *command* to open an application is in the form of `open -a ...` and does not take *input* from `stdout`.

The following assumes that the app name in `file.app.zip` is `file` or the exact name of the app within the `.zip` file:

```
unzip -oq "file.app.zip" -d /tmp; open -a "/tmp/file.app"; sleep 1; rm -r "/tmp/file.app"
```

The above *compound command line* extracts the `file.app.zip` to `/tmp` and then opens it, waits a second and then deletes the `/tmp/file.app`. Note that the *value* of the `sleep` *command* may need to be adjusted in order to not have the app deleted before it's opened and finished running.

Note that the contents of `/tmp`, which is actually `/private/tmp`, is automatically deleted upon reboot. So the *compound command line* could be shortened if you don't care if the app remains in `/tmp'` until next reboot:

```
unzip -oq "file.app.zip" -d /tmp; open -a "/tmp/file.app"
```

Comment: Would replacing the `;` with `&&` add an extra layer of error handling? My understanding is the `&&` ensures the next command only runs if the previous finished with no error.